# How to display the reference group in two message templates?

Tags: php, drupal-8

I installed the Message module on my site :

https://www.drupal.org/project/message

and

https://www.drupal.org/project/group

And I created a custom module from the Message Example sub-module.

Here is the content of the message_activity_stream.info.yml file :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_group_insert().
 */
function message_activity_stream_group_insert(Group $group) {
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_group', 'uid' => $group->get('uid')]);
  $message->set('field_group_reference', $group);
  $message->save();
}
```

I need to insert the group name in the template `mas_create_node` and `mas_create_group`

```
  $message = Message::create(['template' => 'mas_create_node', 'uid' => $node->get('uid')]);
```

How to do this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is the function `message_activity_stream_group_insert` declared twice?

Comment: @dustytrash Because it must be inserted in 2 templates with the same reference field. What should my code look like ?

Comment: try changing the name of one of the functions. E.G `message_activity_stream_group_insert_2` then change wherever it's being called to match the new name

Comment: @dustytrash I updated my question